# How to pass a label in lightning:buttonMenu

Tags: lightning, lightning-buttonmenu

I have the following component:

```
<lightning:buttonMenu iconName="utility:thunder" alternativeText="Settings" onselect="{!c.handleselect}">
    <lightning:menuItem label="Edit" value="{!cc.Id}"/>
    <lightning:menuItem label="Delete" value="{!cc.Id}"/>
</lightning:buttonMenu>
```

**JS controller**

```
handleselect: function(component, event, helper){
    let bhold = event.getParam("label");
    let idhold = event.getParam("value");
    console.log("test 1 : " + event.getSource());
    console.log("test : " + bhold + " : " + idhold);
    if(bhold === "Delete"){
        component.set("v.showdeleteModal", true);
    }
}
```

the lightning button menu is within an aura interation over a series of records.

my question is, how can i pass back both the id and the label, Basically, I would like to pass both "Edit" or "Delete" AND the id regardless of what is chosen

output is bhold is undefined while idhold holds the correct value

Comment: where is it exactly that you are stuck?

Comment: So, I can pass back the value, but I can't figure out how to pass a 2nd variable to the javascript, basically I want to be able to use the label and the value for the menuitem that they selected in my javascript

Comment: have you tried using event.getSource().get("v.value") and event.getSource().get("v.label") instead?

Comment: Just did it, its the same outcome

Comment: your menuItem is inside aura:iteration or menu is inside aura:iteration?

Comment: both are inside an aura:iteration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, this event has only *value* parameter. So if you need more, you have to pass more in this parameter. This looks a bit dirty but will pass label to your controller:

```
<lightning:buttonMenu iconName="utility:thunder" alternativeText="Settings" onselect="{!c.handleselect}">
    <lightning:menuItem label="Edit" value="{!join(',', cc.Id, 'Edit')}"/>
    <lightning:menuItem label="Delete" value="{!join(',', cc.Id, 'Delete')}"/>
</lightning:buttonMenu>
```

So here in your *value* parameter, you will have a string with your cc.Id and label separated by a comma.

```
handleselect: function(component, event, helper){
   let parcedValue = event.getParam("value").split(',');
   let value = parcedValue[0];
   let label = parcedValue[1];

   console.log("value : " + value);
   console.log("label: " + label);

}
```

Also as I can remember **let** does not work in Firefox browser so you might want to use **var** instead.

Answer (score 1):

The approach from 'Oles' would work just fine. However, if you are looking to retrieve all the attributes of the selected menu item such as **"label"**, **"title"**, **"value"** and if you want a generic approach to all the other attributes that you may assign in future. Here is a way.

An ideal way is to use **event.getParam()** like you have used for getting the value `event.getParam('value')`. But `event.getParam('label')` or `event.getParam('title')` does not work as we expected it to. It throws undefined.

Hence we will have to work-around the issue. We can use event.getSource() to determine the attributes of the lightning:menuItem that was selected. We can determine the associated attributes of the selected value ( event.getParam('value') by iterating through the v.body of the menuItem.

> **Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" access="global">
    <lightning:buttonMenu iconName="utility:settings" alternativeText="Settings" onselect="{!c.handleMenuSelect}">
        <lightning:menuItem label="Font" value="font" title="My Font" />
        <lightning:menuItem label="Size" value="size"  title="My Size" />
        <lightning:menuItem label="Format" value="format"  title="My Format" />
    </lightning:buttonMenu>
</aura:component>
```

> **Controller**

```
({
    handleMenuSelect : function(component, event, helper) {        
        console.log(helper.getAttributes(event));        
    }
})
```

> **Helper**

```
({
    getAttributes : function(event) {
        var source = event.getSource().get("v.body");
        var selected_value = event.getParam("value");
        var attr = {};

        if(selected_value && source.length > 0){
            for(var i=0; i<source.length; i++){
                var elements = source[i].attributes.values;
                if(elements.hasOwnProperty('value') && elements['value'].value === selected_value){
                    for(var k in elements){ attr[k] = elements[k].value; }
                }
            }
        }

        return attr;
    }
})
```

> **Sample Output**

[image: Sample Menu Item]

Comment: This is a really creative way to do this, thankyou for your insight! I picked the other answer though because I think it’s simpler and fits more scenarios.